# ARKit - Camera stutters when adding a 3D model to the scene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to place a 3D object in the AR scene when the user taps on a detected plane:

```
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(model3DNode)
```

however, the camera freezes for a few seconds before the 3D model gets rendered. This happens only the first time, any following attempt to place the model gets executed smoothly. This looks pretty strange as the model is quite light (1.3Mb). So far, I have tried different solutions:

- Using a background thread with `DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async`
- Preparing the model before adding it with 
  `sceneView.prepare([model3DNode], completionHandler: { (success) in
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(model3DNode)
  })`

but none of these approaches was successful. Here attached you can find the result of the analysis and it's clearly visible a spike in the GPU/CPU frame time just the first time, all following attempts have no effect (FPS doesn't seem affected).

[image]

The system is running iOS 12 & ARKit 2.0

Comment: Hi Have you find any solution for this? I am facing same issue for first time it takes time to load AR model later it works faster. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing, for now, it looks like a caching problem. It happens only the first time the model gets added